# Bayesian Network/ Number of parameters

Tags: statistics, bayesian-network

Please consider the following Bayesian Network out of $Graphical Models in Applied Multivariate Statistics" by Joe Whittaker:

[image]

Now the factorization property says that the joint probability distributen $P(X_1,\ldots,X_7)$ factorizes according to the graph structure as
$$
P(X_1,\ldots,X_7)=P(X_1)P(X_2|X_1)P(X_3|X_2)P(X_4|X_3)P(X_5)P(X_6|X_2,X_5)P(X_7|X_6).
$$

> > Assuming discrete Random Variables with $r=sp(X_i)$ (here $sp(X_i)$ is the number of possible states of variable $X_i$), a total number of
> >     $$
> > (r-1)+(r-1)r+(r-1)r+(r-1)r+(r-1)+(r-1)r^2+(r-1)r\\=2(r-1)+4(r-1)r+(r-1)r^2
> > $$
> >     parameters are required to represent $P(X_1,\ldots,X_7)$. In contrast, a non-factores representation of $P(X_1,\ldots,X_7)$ requires $r^7-1$ parameters.

---

I do not understand this last passage in grey.

Why does the factored version need 
$$
(r-1)+(r-1)r+(r-1)r+(r-1)r+(r-1)+(r-1)r^2+(r-1)r
$$
parameters?

And why does the non-factored version need
$$
r^7-1
$$
parameters?

Hope you can help me.

With greetings

Answer (score 0):

**Non-Factorised:**

Say we have $3$ random variables for simplicity and that $r=2$: each variable having values $T$ or $F$. To know the full joint probability distribution, we need to know the actual probability value of each row in this table:

$$
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & P(X_1=x_1,\; X_2=x_2,\; X_3=x_3) \\
\hline
T & T & T & 0.1 \\
T & T & F & 0.05 \\
T & F & T & 0.2 \\
T & F & F & 0.05 \\
F & T & T & 0.15 \\
F & T & F & 0.2 \\
F & F & T & 0.05\\
F & F & F & 0.2 \\
\end{array}
$$

In fact, we can deduce the $8^{th}$ probability from the other $7$ because we know they all must sum to $1$.

So we need to know $2^3 - 1 = 7$ specific probability values (parameters). I hope you can see that this generalises to $r^3 - 1$ if there are $r$ choices/states for each variable, and then to $r^7-1$ if there are $7$ variables instead of $3$.

**Factorised:**

We need only as many probability values as required to evaluate every term on the RHS of:

$$P(X_1,\ldots,X_7)=P(X_1)P(X_2|X_1)P(X_3|X_2)P(X_4|X_3)P(X_5)P(X_6|X_2,X_5)P(X_7|X_6).$$

For $P(X_1)$ we need table:

$$
\begin{array}{l|c}
x_1 & P(X_1=x_1) \\
\hline
1 & 0.1 \\
2 & 0.05 \\
\cdots & \cdots \\
10 \quad(r^{th} \text{ row}) & 0.02
\end{array}
$$

Again, the last probability value can be deduced from the others. Therefore, for $P(X_1)$ we need $r-1$ specific probability values (parameters).

For $P(X_6 \mid X_2, X_5)$ we need table:

$$
\begin{array}{lll|c}
x_2 & x_5 & x_6 & P(X_6=x_6 \mid X_2=x_2,\; X_5=x_5) \\
\hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 0.02 \\
1 & 1 & 2 & 0.01 \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
1 & 1 & 10 \quad(r^{th} \text{ row in group}) & 0.03 \\
1 & 2 & 1 & 0.05 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 0.03 \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
1 & 2 & 10 \quad(r^{th} \text{ row in group}) & 0.07 \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
10 & 10 & 10 \quad(r^{th} \text{ row in group}) & 0.04 \\
\end{array}
$$

Each group with the same values for $x_2$ and $x_5$ has $r$ rows. But because the probabilities for the group must sum to $1$, the last probability value in the group can be deduced from the others. So for each group we need $r-1$ probability values (parameters).

We have $r^2$ of these groups in this table because that's how many combinations of values we have for $x_2$ and $x_5$. So this table needs $(r-1)r^2$ probability values specified.

The other terms are worked out similarly and adding up all the numbers of parameters we need, we arrive at:

$$(r-1)+(r-1)r+(r-1)r+(r-1)r+(r-1)+(r-1)r^2+(r-1)r.$$